# Django: presave signal to get file extension in Model

Tags: django, view, model, django-signals

In Django, for file field, its possible to use callable for example `user_directory_path` in the code below.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
extension = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default=get_filename_ext)
```

However, for the extension field I want to use the `get_filename_ext` function so that extension of the file gets saved.

```
def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext
```

Is there something similar in Django model? Or do I have to do this in Django view?

Answer (score 1):

Saving the extension is probably redundant, and thus results in *data duplication*. Since the data is already in the database, it is stored in the `upload`  column.

You can retrieve the filename with `some_mymodel.upload.name`, and thus do further processing on it:

```
from os.path import basename, splitext

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)

    @property
    def extension(self):
        if self.upload:
            return splitext(basename(self.upload.name))[1]
```

We thus here add a property to `MyModel` that will retrieve the extension from the `upload` name. If there is no file, it will return `None`.

Comment: Thanks! In case the database is too big and I want to get lets say all the jpg or png image files then I will have to go through all the records of that table to get my desired files, this was my concern to save the extensions in a separate column.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk: not per se, you could filter on `MyModel.objects.filter(upload__endswith='png')` to get all `.png` files.